# Table with an extra column (comments) without horizontal line-layout

Tags: tables, layout, hline

I would like to comment only some rows of a table.
Is there a way to realize a table with an extra column for comments without overshooting of horizontal lines?

Working example:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l}
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 &\\
        \hline
        1  & 2 & 3 & 4 \textit{Here is a comment!!!}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In this example, I would like to have the "4" cell without any horizontal lines.

Can anybody help?

Thanks, Martin[image: Image illustrates problem.]

Thanks to David, Problem is solved.
The solution was simple,

> use \cline{1-3} not \hline

\cline{1-3} is doing the job.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l}
    \cline{1-3}
    1 & 2 & 3 &\\
    \cline{1-3}
    1  & 2 & 3 & 4 \textit{Here is a comment!!!}\\
    \cline{1-3}
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Solved problem!]

Comment: use `\cline{1-3}` not `\hline`

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. 
Thanks!!!!! 
Great job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\cline{1-3}` instead of  `\hline`